Apache Tika - NoSuchMethodError TarArchiveInputStream.getNextEntry()
I am using versions:

SpringBoot: 3.2.4
Java: JDK 17

Pom used as in docs and based my dependency tree:
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Uses commons-compress lib with version 1.26.1 -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-parsers-standard-package</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Uses commons-compress lib with version 1.24.0 -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <version>4.13.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Uses commons-compress lib with version 1.24.0 -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <version>1.19.7</version>
  </dependency>
 

Using code:
String htmlFile = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><!-- HTML Codes by Quackit.com --><title></title><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"><style>body {background-color:#ffffff;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:top left;background-attachment:fixed;}h1{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;color:#000000;background-color:#ffffff;}p {font-family:Georgia, serif;font-size:14px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;color:#000000;background-color:#ffffff;}</style></head><body><h1>test</h1><p>test2</p></body></html>";

Tika tika = new Tika();

// this throw exception
text = tika.parseToString(TikaInputStream.get(htmlFile.getBytes())); 

// This is not working too - same exception
text = tika.parseToString(new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlFile.getBytes()));

Exception - relevant part:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveEntry org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream.getNextEntry()'
at org.apache.tika.detect.zip.TikaArchiveStreamFactory.detect(TikaArchiveStreamFactory.java:293) ~[tika-parser-zip-commons-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
at org.apache.tika.detect.zip.DefaultZipContainerDetector.detectArchiveFormat(DefaultZipContainerDetector.java:124) ~[tika-parser-zip-commons-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
at org.apache.tika.detect.zip.DefaultZipContainerDetector.detect(DefaultZipContainerDetector.java:175) ~[tika-parser-zip-commons-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
at org.apache.tika.detect.CompositeDetector.detect(CompositeDetector.java:84) ~[tika-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:177) ~[tika-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
at org.apache.tika.Tika.parseToString(Tika.java:525) ~[tika-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
at org.apache.tika.Tika.parseToString(Tika.java:495) ~[tika-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
at org.apache.tika.Tika.parseToString(Tika.java:557) ~[tika-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
at ... -> tika.parseToString(...

I tried to use a different approach to use tika parsing, but I got the same exception as I debugged - the first approach uses this second in tika libraries - I tried this second approach:
AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
parser.parse(TikaInputStream.get(htmlFile.getBytes()), handler, metadata);
text = handler.toString();

I tried to use Tika version 2.9.1 and everything works fine as months before.
But I want the latest versions without vulnerabilities. So I tried to remove tika-parsers-standard-package from pom and as I debugged tika libraries, it went further but returned just empty text because of missing parser for HTML-like files(as I debugged in tika libraries), logically. So there is some tika bug in libraries or am I doing something wrong?

Have you hard-coded a dependency on an older version of Commons Compress?

No, but I tried now, it is strange, I declared pom dependency of commons-compress lib with version 1.26.1 below tika dependencies and now it is working even with tika 2.9.2. Thanks, you can write it as answer, I will accept. Hardcoding commons-compress dependency again below tika dependencies helped - but before I saw in dependency tree that tika 2.9.2 uses commons-compress 1.26.1 but that not worked.

My dependency tree also show places where commons-compress is used: - junit:junit:jar:4.13.2 - org.apache.tika:tika-parser-webarchive-module:jar:2.9.2 - org.testcontainers:testcontainers:jar:1.19.7 but all those dependencies use commons-compress 1.24.0 but tika 2.9.2 uses 1.26.1... and without declaring commons-compress in pom with version 1.26.1, those libs somehow conflicts each other, after adding 1.26.1 commons-compress - junit and testcontainers use 1.26.1 too ... I will update pom in my question

So I will post an answer for others with the same issue. This helped me:
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
      <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
      <artifactId>tika-parsers-standard-package</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- By adding this the problem is solved -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
      <version>1.26.1</version>
    </dependency>

I also investigated why this was happening with the following command:
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose | grep 'omitted for conflict' | grep 'commons-compress'

Command response in my case:
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.25.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.26.1)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.26.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.24.0)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.25.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.24.0)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.26.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.24.0)

It means Tika used version 1.24.0 because of conflicts in transitive dependencies between tika-parsers-standard-package and junit/testcontainers dependencies. By hardcoding commons-compress library to the 1.26.1 version, all dependencies used 1.26.1 commons-compress so Tika used the correct version too and is working now as expected.

Thank you brother! You saved my life and a lot of nerves. I had the almost identical exception (not Tar but Zip) - App was working fine on developing with glassfish, but not worked on prod with tomcat. After I changed commons-compress from 1.12 to 1.26.1 - everything is going fine
